# zoom animation on image

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, zooming

I am trying to do the following:

I have a view that displays image. I have implemented pinchgesturerecognizer to do zoom in/out. How can I do animation and display the image exactly the way user zoomed image with the same velocity and at the same location. For e.g, if I zoom in at right top corner the image should replay with zoom at right top corner and at same speed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replay, as in _not_ while the user is pinching? If so, the same speed at every moment of the animation or just the same duration?

Comment: yes not while user is pinching, preferably at the tap of a replay button. Speed can be evenly distributed but for the same duration.

Comment: Once you are able to record where and how the user pinches, replaying it won't be difficult. It just similar but the opposite (apply value instead of recording it)

Comment: Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I have had also dome some research for the same kind of requirement for one of my project.

What i have found/done was: I have added my image view to a scrollview.
Then i have set all the scrollview properties like max-min zoomScale, frame, delegate, userInteractionEnabled, scrollEnabled, etc.

So now you don't require to manage as per pinch level, scrollview itself manages all the zoom level and scrolling part.

Hope this will help you.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: This answer doesn't meet my requirements. I need to be able to execute the pinch zoom data thru some function so that image in the view zooms in same way as user did it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a recording system. Off the top of my head, you could do something like this:

Record the current timestamp when you begin the user's drawing sequence:

NSTimeInterval startTime = [NSDate intervalSinceReferenceDate];

As the user pinches and/or zooms, record the amount of elapsed time from the start time, and the change you make, for all changes. I'd suggest building an array of change records, where each record has an elapsed time field and the new zoom scale.

If you draw the user's changes as discrete renders at different sizes, just record and replay each elapsed time and new size.

If you animate between sizes, record the time interval and time offset for each animation.

Then to play back, you'd run through each record and execute the same changes over the same time intervals, using a timer, performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, or something similar.